# SQL increment SELECT column by +1

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to figure it out with searches, but I am running into deprecated code and conflicting advice.

I am trying to select the number of yes votes with an ID that is passed through the url. I want to then add one to that number and UPDATE the table. I'm not quite sure exactly where I've gone wrong.

EDIT: I have tried using yesvotes=yesvotes +1 and that gets me from 0 to 1 but will not get me from 1 to 2 or any further. I just need a clicked link (which passes the needed 'ID' through the URL and retrieved using $_GET) to add 1 to the 'yesvotes' column. I thought it was a straightforward process but it seems like I am missing something or have a syntax error somewhere.

Sorry for the newb shit, just trying to learn.

```
    <?php

    $entry = $_GET ['id'];

    include 'connect.php';

    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM yesvotes WHERE ID = '" . $entry ."'"); 

    $vote = $result->fetch_array();

    $votetotal = $vote++;


    $sql = 
    "UPDATE showsubmit
    SET yesvotes = '" . $votetotal . "'
    WHERE ID = '" . $entry . "'";

    $conn->query($sql);

    $conn->close();


    ?>
```

Comment: If you just want to add 1 to the existing value, you can simply do `UPDATE showsubmit SET yesvotes=yesvotes+1 WHERE ID=....`

Comment: What's the concurrency issue of this? This seems like a problem.

Comment: `$votetotal = $vote++;` You've got a problem here. `$vote` is an array, not a value. Since you're using `fetch_array()` (and you don't enumerate your fields) you should use `$votetotal = $vote[0] + 1;`

Comment: I tried doing "yesvotes = yesvotes +1 ...etc" before and it successfully got me from 0 to 1 but would not go any further. no matter how many times I run the script (click the link) it just stays at 1.

Comment: Machavity, what is the significance of the [0] in the code you suggested?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need all this ... you can perform a `update-join` like

```
UPDATE showsubmit ss
JOIN ( SELECT ID, COUNT(*) as total
       FROM yesvotes WHERE ID = 2334 ) XXX ON ss.ID = XXX.ID
    SET ss.yesvotes = XXX.total + 1;
```

Comment: Sorry, this is a little above my head. I really want to understand but may need a little nudge.